# Navigator / Geolocation getCurrentPosition inconsistent response times

Tags: javascript, geolocation, navigator, reverse-geocoding

Working with the navigator API provided by browser (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) and sometimes it takes 4 seconds, sometimes 5 seconds, sometimes over 10 seconds (have reached 50+ seconds)

Working on a consumer facing app and it's necessary to grab the location to see if they are valid to see some promotions based on their location. However, the long waiting times can be bad for user experience (waiting 10+ seconds not good) so is there any explanation / advice / alternatives I can do to make it quicker? And in case after a timeout, best practice to handle it?

And yes I have set the highAccuracy to false:

```
const locationOptions = {
                enableHighAccuracy: false,
                timeout: 10000,
                maximumAge: Infinity
            }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not much you can control with regard to time. Browsers use a third party service to make the request to so you are at the mercy of network latency and third party service response times as well as whatever other synchronous script that is running when response gets returned and gets sent to event loop